# Why does C++ rand() seem to generate only numbers of the same order of magnitude?

Tags: c++, c, math, random

In a small application written in C/C++, I am facing a problem with the `rand` function and maybe the seed :

I want to produce a sequence of random numbers that are of different orders, i.e. with different logarithm values (base 2). But it seems that all the numbers produced are of the same order, fluctuating just between 2^25 and 2^30.

Is it because `rand()` is seeded with Unix time which is by now a relatively big number? What am I forgetting ? 
I am seeding `rand()` only once at the beginning of the `main()`.

Comment: Did you use srand (time(NULL)); to initialize random seed?

Comment: FWIW so, is it C or C++? If by C/C++ you mean you can actually use C++, and the mention of C was just random, maybe this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/binomial_distribution can help.

Comment: Also note (I'm pretty sure of this) that **the exact workings of `rand()` is a library implementation detail**. So even if you use the same seed, moving to a different compiler or even standard library version, you are not guaranteed to get the same output. Hence for questions like this, it is occasionally helpful to at least specify the environment (compiler and standard library by name and exact version number).

Comment: Unfortunately you were betting on the wrong horse. Seed should not be your problem. Your problem was wrong expected distribution. Since unbiased programer would expect `rand()` to return uniformly distributed numbers (documentation with high Google ranking explicitly says so) I don't think this question is useful for future readers. That's why down vote but don't let it discourage you from using SO.

Comment: rand is implementation defined, so use boost, which has much higher quality and  well defined algorithms.

Comment: Most rand implementations that I've seen return a perfectly uniform distribution, where no number is ever repeated and every possible number is returned. I tested rand with a 1<<32 array (4GB), verifying that each rand() call hasn't had that value returned before and at the end verified that every possible number was returned. The behavior of the sequence never being different is expected. Starting at any seed, the sequence of random numbers will always be the same.

Comment: @doug65536 "...where no number is ever repeated"  -- that's not random!  I could fund my retirement at the craps table if my rand() dice never returned the same number twice  until every possible number was returned.

Comment: @ChrisGregg Of course it's not random. That's why it's called a __pseudo__ random number generator.

Comment: @doug65536 actually raises a *really* good point - a PRNG is only as good as its ability to avoid repetition - its periodicity.  See [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) for some details on this.

Comment: @doug65536 No, that's not why it's called a pseudo random number generator.  The name "pseudo random number generator" has nothing to do with producing every combination before a repeat, and everything to do with an approximation of random behavior through algorithmic means.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Don't mistake periodicity with a repeat of individual numbers.  From the Wikipedia article you cited: "a repeated result does not imply that the end of the period has been reached, since its internal state may be larger than its output."  It would be very, very bad if a PRNG produced a value and then was guaranteed not to produce that value again until all values were returned.

Comment: @ChrisGregg What? I said it is called "pseudo" random because it's not random. Pseudo means "fake", "pretending to be something it is not". You thought rand() could be used for gambling, now you're suddenly an expert on random number theory? Come on.

Comment: Doug65536, nobody is picking fights. They are just stating correctly that you are wrong.

A PRNG could quite happily churn out the following if I wanted a RAND between 1 and 10: 

2 4 7 2 8 1 5 9 7 3

That would be entirely valid, despite the multiple 2s and 7s. I think you are getting the PRNG confused with the shuffle facility on your iPhone.

Comment: "Random" just means that every item has an equal probability of being selected (or has a probability equal to the proportion of those items in the population, which is the same thing when each item appears only once). If no number in the sequence is ever repeated, then it's the complete opposite of random, since you'll know that once a number has come up, it'll have *no* chance of being selected until the entire cycle is complete. Obviously any PRNG is ultimately deterministic once you pick the seed, but that's a very different thing from *you* being able to predict something about the result.

Comment: In many simple random number implementations, when a number is repeated, the subsequent sequence is repeated, since the formula depends only on the current value and the generator keeps only one seed. Therefore, large period (or full period cover for the entire space) is considered beneficial. However, the *internal* period of the rand generator may be much larger than 32-bits, so when mapped back into 32-bits there may be duplicates while there are no duplicates in the internal representation.

Answer (score 479, accepted):

There are only 3% of numbers between 1 and 2<sup>30</sup> which are NOT between 2<sup>25</sup> and 2<sup>30</sup>. So, this sounds pretty normal :)

Because 2<sup>25</sup> / 2<sup>30</sup> = 2<sup>-5</sup> = 1/32 = 0.03125 = 3.125%

Comment: Aye, good point ! There are 31 times more numbers between 2^25 and 2^30 than between 1 and 2^25 :) thanks for the quick answer. I need to rethink the program then. Question answered.

Comment: @TallaronMathias Consider truncating the number through `>>` bitshifting -- this will give you smaller numbers.  (Or taking a modulus with `%`.)

Comment: I would expect this to be obvious to most programmers:  Any unsigned integer less than 2^25 must have its first 7 bits equal to `0` - and if every bit is random...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - if probabilities were obvious, casinos would be out of business.

Comment: @BrettHale - I don't think programmers are a casino's target demographic though.

Comment: same answer as the problem : "What is the probability of getting 5 tails in 5 toss of a fair coin? " :-)

Comment: Side note:  To get a random 32-bit integer with a fairly even distribution of base 2 orders of magnitude, you could try: rand() & ((1 << (rand() % 33)) - 1).  There may be a somewhat cleaner way to do it but that's the simplest I could come up with quickly.  Actually kind of a neat problem.

Comment: Yes. Make a random float between 0 and 1, multiple with 32 (as float), take its logarithm (as float), divide with the logarithm of 2 (as float), take the exponential of the result (as float), and finally convert this to integer. You will get floating numbers, but in a logarithmical distribution. I think to this: int(exp(log(rand()*32)/log(2))). That means, that the numbers with lower exponents will come with bigger occurrence, for example 2^10<x<2^11 will have the same probability as 2^11<x<2^12 .

Answer (score 272):

The lighter green is the region between 0 and 2<sup>25</sup>; the darker green is the region between 2<sup>25</sup> and 2<sup>30</sup>. The ticks are powers of 2.

[image: distribution]

Answer (score 42):

You need to be more precise: you want different base 2 logarithm values but what *distribution* do you want for this? The standard rand() functions generate a uniform distribution, you will need to transform this output using the *quantile* function associated with the distribution that you want.

If you tell us the distribution then we can tell you the `quantile` function you need.

Comment: +1, _distribution_ is the crucial term. It doesn't really make sense to talk about random numbers when nothing is known about the distribution. Uniform is just a special case, albeit an important one. Might be a good place to point out various distributions from the C++11 standard library.

Answer (score 18):

If you want different orders of magnitude, why not simply try `pow(2, rand())`? Or perhaps choose the order directly as rand(), as Harold suggested?

Comment: good idea, but you should fix your answer using pow instead of ^ (which is the logical xor operator, not power, in C language).

Comment: Since `rand()` can go up to `RAND_MAX`, you really need to scale your random number so the result doesn't overflow...

Comment: @Floris: but if you scale a small countable range on a very large range, you will have LOTS of holes, which is probably not what OP is expecting.

Answer (score 13):

@C4stor made a great point. But, for a more general case and easier to understand for human (base 10): for the range from 1 to 10^n, ~90% of the numbers are from 10^(n-1) to 10^n, therefore, ~99% of the numbers go from 10^(n-2) to 10^n. Keep adding as many decimals as you want.

Funny mathematics, if you keep doing this for n, you can see that from 1 to 10^n, [99.9999...% = 100%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.9999999999) of the numbers are from 10^0 to 10^n with this method.

Now about code, if you want a random number with random orders of magnitude, from 0 to 10^n, you could do:

1. Generate a small random number from 0 to n
2. If you know the range that n has, generate a big random number of order 10^k where k > max{n}.
3. Cut the longer random number to get the n digits of this big random number.

Comment: You're completely correct, but for a REALLY easy to understand answer, the OP should ask himself why 90% of the random numbers between 1 and 100 are two digits.

Answer (score 13):

The basic (and correct) answer was already given and accepted above: there are 10 numbers between 0 and 9, 90 numbers between 10 and 99, 900 between 100 and 999, etc.

For a computationally efficient way to get a distribution with *approximately* logarithmic distribution, you want to right-shift your random number by a random number:

```
s = rand() & 31; // a random number between 0 and 31 inclusive, assuming RAND_MAX = 2^32-1
r = rand() >> s; // right shift
```

It's not perfect, but it's much faster than computing `pow(2, rand()*scalefactor)`. It will be "lumpy" in the sense that the distribution will be uniform for numbers within a factor 2 (uniform for 128 to 255, half the density for 256 to 1023, etc).

Here is a histogram of the frequency of the numbers 0 to 31 (in 1M samples):

[image]

Comment: nitpick: this encourages very small numbers more than one might expect.  The probability of getting a zero is significantly higher than a 10.

Comment: Well - the whole point of this is to encourage small numbers, so I'm glad it's working! I ran a Monte Carlo simulation, and this is giving me a factor 2 drop in probability as numbers double - not unlike a log distribution. Updated answer with a picture.

Comment: no, I mean, with `rand()>>(rand()&31);`, one would intuitively expect 1/32nd of the numbers to have 32 bits, and 1/32nd of the numbers to have 31 bits, and 1/32nd of the numbers to have 30 bits, etc.  But that's _not_ the results you're getting, only about than 1/64th of the numbers would result in 32 bits, while almost half should be 0.  Since my mental math disagrees with your measurements, I'll have to do my own measurements to figure this out.

Comment: [Yeah, my measurements match my theory](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=834eb55168b2a01bead5b1dde6ce4da7-803889f054654ad4b92ce24ea171578e).  Since your x-axis isn't logarithmic, you're overlooking the problem.

Comment: I don't mean to say your code is wrong.  It's probably what I would do.  It just deserves a warning that the results aren't _quite_ distributed as one might expect.

Comment: Also note theres no results with 32 bits

Comment: [This variant is slower but gives 1-32 bits with an even distribution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=626c1e16ed161ff20b0504b2f7fd3100-803889f054654ad4b92ce24ea171578e).

Comment: Hmmm that's strange. I am missing something obvious - how is your code getting away with `block[log2(0)]++;`? NVM - I just noticed how you defined `log2`. I will have to think more about this. Thanks for the feedback and code samples!

Comment: It occurs to my that my "evenly distributed" version will never come up with a zero.  Oh well.

Comment: I think the problem comes from thinking of 0 as a 1 bit number... that's the kind of conundrum you run into when you mix integers and logarithms. It's been a good exercise though and you gave me something to think about. "Test the limits of your algorithm" - it never gets old.

Answer (score 5):

There are exactly equal number of numbers between 0 and 2^29 and 2^29 and 2^30.

Another way of looking at the problem: consider binary representation of the random number you generate, the probability that the highest bit is 1 equals 1/2, and, therefore, you get order 29 in half cases. What you want is to see a number that would be below 2^25, but that means 5 highest bits are all zero, which happens with a low probability of 1/32. Chances are that even if you run it for a long time you will never see the order below 15 at all (the probability is something like rolling 6 6 times in a row).

Now, the part of your question about the seed. No, the seed cannot possibly determine the range the numbers are generated from, it just determines the first, initial element. Think of rand() as a sequence of all possible numbers in the range (predetermined permutation). The seed determines where you start drawing numbers from the sequence. This is why if you want (pseudo) randomness, you use current time to initialize the sequence: you do not care that the position you start from is not uniformly distributed, all that matters is that you never start from the same position.

Answer (score 2):

use 
`pow(2,rand())`
it will give the answers in order of desired magnitude!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use random numbers from an online service you can use wget for that, you may want to see 
you can also use services like random.org for your random number generation , you can catch them using wget and then reading the numbers from the downloaded file

```
wget -q https://www.random.org/integers/?num=100&min=1&max=100&col=5&base=10&format=html&rnd=new -O new.txt
```

http://programmingconsole.blogspot.in/2013/11/a-better-and-different-way-to-generate.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. please refrain from posting links as answers. You can provide a detailed sketch of an answer leaving the details to be read via links.